# jmeter pass command line variables into a jmx

Tags: variables, jmeter, jmx

I'm trying to automate some perf testing. I'd to pass server locations into a generic jmx from a Jenkins job. I'd like to be able to do something like:

> jmeter -n -t foo.jmx -JtestingIP=IP

and have foo.jmx pick up `testingIP`.

What is the proper way to do this? When I run that jmeter command, it says that the variable has been stored, but inserting either `${testingIP}` or `${\_\_P(testingIP,)}` into the jmx results in `${testingIP}` or `${\_\_P(testingIP,)}` to be interpreted as just a string.

What am I doing wrong/not doing at all? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 80):

All you need to do is start your JMeter from the command line (or shell) with the **-J** option.
For example :

> -JTestIP=10.0.0.1

And in your script, to get the value, just use function **_P**:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P

Example:

> ```
> ${__P(TestIP)}
> ```

That should do it.

Note you should put a default value in case you run the script without passing that JMeter property like:

> ${__P(TestIP,1.1.1.1)}

Comment: Works in jmeter 3.0. Thank you!

Comment: It worked for me. I am using Jmeter Java 1.0

Comment: It requires to add a `Config Element` in JMeter for `User Defined Variables` to include custom variables/properties defined by the programmer.

Answer (score 14):

1. Open the **Jmeter** file (jmx) in Jmeter GUI and add parameters as in this screenshot:

[image]
Click on **Save** button.

2. Now, run the command with these parameters, for example:

   ```
    jmeter -t TestPlan.jmx -Jthreads=10 -Jcount=50 -Jrumpup=5
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at this link http://mkbansal.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/jmeter-command-line-script-execution-with-arguments/. Also I would try to specify default value, like `${__P(testingFromCommandLineIP,defaultIP)}` where `testingFromCommandLineIP` -- argument you specify when running test plan from command line, `defaultIP` -- default value

Answer (score 5):

You have two options to send parameters to jmeter.

**First**: Sets a system property value.

```
-Dproperty=value
```

If value is a string that contains spaces, then you must enclose the string in double quotation marks.

*Example*:

```
java -Dmydir="some string" -jar ApacheJmeter.jar -n -t PerformanceTest.jmx
```

Reading parameters in jsr223 beanshell:

```
log.info("mydir:" + System.getProperty("mydir"));
```

Reading parameters in request sampler with Bean Shell function:

```
${__BeanShell(System.getProperty("mydir"))}
```

**Second**: Defines a local JMeter property

```
-J[prop_name]=[value]
```

*Example*:

```
jmeter -n -t PerformanceTest.jmx -Jmyparamter=4 -Jduration=300
```

Reading properties in request sampler with Bean Shell function:

```
${__P(duration)}
```